# Create sitemap webpart

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-designer, site

I created Table of Contents webpart to just display the Sub Sites, but it is showing the lists (Library, Lists, Discussions, etc...). How can I just show the sub-sites and sub-sub-sites using a web part?
I am on SharePoint 2010 Standard.

Answer (score 1):

There is one built in: SharePoint 2010 > Edit > Insert > Web Part > Content Rollup > Table of Contents.

Will that solve your problem?

Comment: As I mentioned in my original post, I am using the Table of Contents web part, BUT I wan to display JUST the SITES.

Comment: My bad. I don't think you can do that out of the box. Perhaps this is a solution: http://sharepoint247.com/sharepoint2010/new-version-of-the-subsites-webpart-available-as-a-free-download/

Comment: I tried uploading the web part, but it is empty and looks nothing like the screenshot on the page. My [screenshot](http://i.minus.com/iby30iFmJ1CBkN.png)